# trying to add text at the end of a line at the fist occurrence of a variable in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I've attached the text(s) file I'm working with below: 
using sed I can get a result which adds the text but it's being added to every line that contained my variable which happened to be "33" in this case. I would only like the text "*SLOTS*" added to the first occurrence in the file and basically stop once the first is encountered. sed adds the text "*SLOTS*" to every line that contains my variable in my text file there are other columns that happen to have the same value as my variable. I've searched through numerous websites to get the desired results but haven't had any luck trying awk or other sed examples. any help would be greatly appreciated.

here's my current sed line:
        sed '/\b'$slot_drill'\b/s/$/*SLOTS*/' $slot_card > $new_slot_card

what my current sed line outputs:

d25104-1.dr -- PANEL SIZE: 18x24

### Drilled Slots: Yes

Tool  Tool     Spindle Feed   Hits   Max  Bits Path     Time

### Size     Speed   Rate          Hits               (Min)

T01   126      1.0     1.0    58     1600 0.0  182.8    1.7
T02   250      1.0     1.0    9      1600 0.0  67.5     0.7
T03   12       1.0     1.0    3965   1600 2.5  514.4    4.6
T04   31       1.0     1.0    65     1600 0.0  62.0     0.6
T05   33       1.0     1.0    569    1600 0.4  46.6     0.4     *SLOTS*
T06   35       1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  45.3     0.4     *SLOTS*
T07   41       1.0     1.0    97     1600 0.1  79.6     0.7
T08   42       1.0     1.0    135    1600 0.1  104.6    0.9
T09   43       1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  53.0     0.5     *SLOTS*
T10   49.2     1.0     1.0    65     1600 0.0  44.2     0.4
T11   52       1.0     1.0    17     1600 0.0  40.7     0.4
T12   63.5     1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  55.6     0.5     *SLOTS*

### T13   98       1.0     1.0    25     1600 0.0  52.0     0.5

Total                         5104        3.2  1348.2   12.5

output that is desired:

d25104-1.dr -- PANEL SIZE: 18x24

### Drilled Slots: Yes

Tool  Tool     Spindle Feed   Hits   Max  Bits Path     Time

### Size     Speed   Rate          Hits               (Min)

T01   126      1.0     1.0    58     1600 0.0  182.8    1.7
T02   250      1.0     1.0    9      1600 0.0  67.5     0.7
T03   12       1.0     1.0    3965   1600 2.5  514.4    4.6
T04   31       1.0     1.0    65     1600 0.0  62.0     0.6
T05   33       1.0     1.0    569    1600 0.4  46.6     0.4     *SLOTS*
T06   35       1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  45.3     0.4
T07   41       1.0     1.0    97     1600 0.1  79.6     0.7
T08   42       1.0     1.0    135    1600 0.1  104.6    0.9
T09   43       1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  53.0     0.5
T10   49.2     1.0     1.0    65     1600 0.0  44.2     0.4
T11   52       1.0     1.0    17     1600 0.0  40.7     0.4
T12   63.5     1.0     1.0    33     1600 0.0  55.6     0.5

### T13   98       1.0     1.0    25     1600 0.0  52.0     0.5

Total                         5104        3.2  1348.2   12.5

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvrzg.jpg)

Comment: Instead of using images to show your output, please use plain text, as it makes your question a lot clearer. [Edit] your question to show us your current and desired output, using a code block (select the text, then Ctrl-k).

Comment: Thank you Tom, I tried pasting the text into the question area but I lost all of it's formatting. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what you are asking.  A good minimal example would probably omit the shell variables and take the line you are working with as completely independent so that other people can run it on their own systems.

However, it sounds as if you are just asking how to limit `sed`'s `s` command to working only for the first line it finds that is a match.  In general, I think the way is to prefix a range to the command and use `0` for the beginning of the range.  For example: `sed '0,/foo/ {s/foo/bar}'` will replace only the first instance of foo that it finds with bar.

This is an answer to this sort of problem given at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188264/want-to-substitute-only-first-occurence-with-sed

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to only substitute the first line that it finds a match. I've tried  '0,  and it will add the text to every line up to the match. I'm not sure why it behaves this way, perhaps it's because the first line of the file is a blank line?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

on a simplified file

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

append SLOT to the first occurrence of the variable `slot`, let's say 3.

```
$ awk -v value="$slot" '$1==value && !c++{$0=$0 "SLOT"} 1' file

1
2
3SLOT
1
2
3
```

Looking at your example you'll need to use `$2==value``

Comment: thank you karakfa, my variable will be in a certain column so I substituted /3/ with $2==$my_var but I get an error of " s: event not found"

Comment: you need to pass the variable to `awk`,  see my updated example.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I believe I'm on the right path now.